# 2 and more characters are shown when onclick function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard

***Functionality:***

User have to click on the drawn keyboard keypad on the screen to input name and email. Character will then be displayed in the input box.

***What has been done:***

Created the html keyboard and also the keyboard script. Hence, functionally, the keyboard is shown and the keyboard functionality is working.

***Issue:***

when the page is first loaded, the keyboard function is working properly, hence when the page is loaded and when user clicks on the keyboard, the character is displayed. However, after a period of idletime, when user uses the keyboard, the character displayed is not displayed correctly.

Hence, the error features is this: e.g if user clicks on the character 'c' on the keyboard, rightfully, 'c' is supposed to be displayed in the input box, however, at this point when user clicks on'c', multiple 'c' is being displayed in the input box.

I am at a loss at what has happened and how could I rectify the issue. This issue only happens after a period of idle.

```js
function Start() {


  //Method  call to slide and fade in second page to the left padding
  $('#Email_Page').fadeIn({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false,
    complete: function() {

      //Keyboard Script
      $('#keyboard li').click(function() {
        console.log("click");
        idleTime = 0;

        var $this = $(this),
          character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable
        console.log(character);
        // Shift keys
        if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
          $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
          $('.symbol span').toggle();

          shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
          capslock = false;
          return false;
        }

        // Caps lock
        if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
          $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
          capslock = true;
          return false;
        }

        // Delete
        if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
          var html = $write.val();

          $write.val(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
          return false;
        }

        // Clear
        if ($this.hasClass('clear')) {
          var html = $write.val();

          $write.val("");
          return false;
        }

        // Special characters
        if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
        if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
        if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
        if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

        // Uppercase letter
        if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();

        // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
        if (shift === true) {
          $('.symbol span').toggle();
          if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

          shift = false;
        }

        // Add the character
        $write.val($write.val() + character);
      });

    }
  });
}
```

```css
// Keyboard CSS
 .keyboard {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.keyboard li {
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2 2 2 2;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #716b6c;
  background: #e3d7d8;
  border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.capslock,
.tab,
.left-shift {
  clear: left;
}
.keyboard .tab,
.keyboard .delete {
  width: 165px;
}
.keyboard .capslock {
  width: 101px;
}
.keyboard .return {
  width: 101px;
}
.keyboard .left-shift {
  width: 165px;
}
.keyboard .right-shift {
  width: 165px;
}
.lastitem {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.keyboard .space {
  clear: left;
  width: 750px;
}
.on {
  display: none;
}
.keyboard li:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!--Email Buttons-->
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1080" top="550px">
  <tr style="height: 1920;">
    <td width="1080">

      <ul class="keyboard" id="keyboard" style="z-index:2; position:absolute;left:120px; top:850px; color: #000000;">
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">1</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">2</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">3</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">4</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">5</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">6</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">7</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">8</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">9</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol lastitem"><span class="off">0</span></li></font>

        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter" style="clear: left;">q</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">w</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">e</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">r</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">t</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">y</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">u</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">i</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">o</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter lastitem">p</li></font>

        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter" style="clear: left;">a</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">s</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">d</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">f</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">g</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">h</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">j</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">k</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">l</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter lastitem">z</li></font>

        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter" style="clear: left;">x</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">c</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">v</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">b</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">n</li></fint>
                            <font face ="CenturyGothic"><li class="letter">m</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">@</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">.</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol"><span class="off">-</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol lastitem"><span class="off">_</span></li></font>

        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol" style="clear: left; width: 85px;"><span class="off">.com</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol" style="width: 215px;"><span class="off">@hotmail.com</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol" style="width: 215px;"><span class="off">@yahoo.com</span></li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="symbol" style="width: 215px;"><span class="off">@gmail.com</span></li></font>

        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="clear" style=" clear: left; width: 370px;">Clear</li></font>
        <font face="CenturyGothic"> <li class="delete lastitem" style="width: 370px;">Delete</li></font>

        <font face="CenturyGothic"><li class="space lastitem">Space &nbsp;</li></font>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use `bind` to bind click event only once. Instead of everytime `off` and `on` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register `click` event every time `#Email_Page` fade in.

remove event first before adding new event :

```
//Method  call to slide and fade in second page to the left padding
$('#Email_Page').fadeIn({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false,
    complete: function() {

        //Keyboard Script
        $('#keyboard li').off('click').on('click',function() {    
            ..........
            etc etc .....
```

Comment: Thanks, just wanna ask a theoretical question, hence, for every  onclick input, do you have to remove the event first before adding new event when a 'selector' fadesIn??

Comment: If you call `$('#keyboard li').click(function(){....})` multiple time (example=twice), it will bind 2 anonymous function to `click` event on `li`. So if you click `li`, those 2 function will be called.

Comment: In your code, every time `Email_Page` is faded in, one new anonymous function will be attached to `li`'s `click` event.

Comment: last question, will it be the same syntax for a `dblclick` function call too?